# Can't eliminate spaces in the nav-pill stacked menu i have created. (bootstrap)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to eliminate the spaces between every stacked pill.

With the code i have right now, the nav-pill seems to work as expected, but there are spaces in between every pill that appear to be unwanted button/links. I tried to look for solutions online, that included setting the margin-right:0, but it just didn't seem to work.

**Here is the code for the nav-pill in the html file:**

```
<div class = "container-fluid">
        <div class = "menu">
            <div class = "row" bg = "warning">
                <div class = "col-lg-3">
                <ul class = "nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                    <li class  = "nav-header">Menu</li>
                    <li class = "active"><a href = "mbIndex.php">Home</li>
                    <li><div class = "glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"><a href = "mbAddOrders.php">Add Order</span></li>
                    <li><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span><a href = "mbNewOrders.php">Orders</li>
                    <li><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span><a href = "mbInOutProducts.php">Products</li>
                    <li><a href = "mbRecords.php">Archive</li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

**And here is the bootstrap.theme.min.css file i edited:**

```
.jumbotron{
  background-color: lightyellow;
}

ul{
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
ul.nav-pills li.active a{
border-top: 3px solid;
border-radius: 2px;
}
ul.nav-pills li:hover a{
    border-top: 3px solid light blue;
}
ul.nav-pills li a{
    background-color: #eee;
    margin-right: 0;
}

ul.nav-pills li a{
    background-color: lightyellow;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your markup is slightly chaotic, as it´s missing closing anchor tags (`</a>`). The format to add a menu item should be following:

```
<li><a href="..."><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-..." aria-hidden="true"></span> My name for the link</a></li>
```

Try the following markup:

```
<ul class = "nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
   <li class = "nav-header">Menu</li>
   <li class = "active"><a href = "mbIndex.php">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href = "mbAddOrders.php"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add Order</a></li>
   <li><a href = "mbNewOrders.php"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Orders</a></li>
   <li><a href = "mbInOutProducts.php"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span> Products</a></li>
   <li><a href = "mbRecords.php">Archive</li>
</ul>
```